# Deserialize HttpError ModelState

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Wit the latest webapi bits I now have

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
```

My client is an MVC website that reads the value from the response. I finally got it to read the HttpError object from the response, but loading the ModelState is... not intuitive to say the least.

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

```
var httpError = response.Read<HttpError>();
 var errors = httpError["ModelState"] as JObject;

 foreach (var error in errors)
 foreach (var message in error.Value.Values<string>())
 {
     modelState.AddModelError(error.Key, message);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

While an error response, as you've identified, can readily be deserialised into an HttpError, the ModelState value within it only ends up as a JObject.

You've probably already tried something like:

```
var errors = ((JObject)errorMsg["ModelState"])
             .ToObject<ModelStateDictionary>();
```

Or maybe:

```
var errors = ((JObject)errorMsg["ModelState"])
             .ToObject<Dictionary<string, ICollection<ModelError>>>();
```

And found that it won't convert. The best alternative I could find was:

```
var errors = ((JObject)errorMsg["ModelState"])
             .ToObject<Dictionary<string, IList<string>>>();
```

Which makes your iteration *marginally* neater:

```
foreach (var err in errors)
foreach (var msg in err.Value)
{
    modelStateDictionary.AddModelError(err.Key, msg);
}
```

The problem, as I see it, is a string won't deserialise to a ModelError instance, and is further compounded by ModelErrorCollection unfortunately hiding its base class constructor of `Collection(IList list)`.

Comment: P.S. Check out the ASP.NET Web Stack to see the implementations of the relevant classes for yourself. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e54cc5b2a9f4

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the API calls? Client-side? If so, I noticed Brad Wilson using the below format for receiving AJAX responses via jQuery in a recent demo. This may not be what you're looking for but it's been working well for me:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/apicontorller/action/",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {

        },
        404: function () {
            alert('404');
        },
        400: function () {
            alert('invalid');
        },
        500: function () {
            alert('error');
        },
        // ...
    }
});
```

The nice thing about this is you can handle the actual HTTP status codes. In my experience, error messages/data can be accessed by providing a parameter to the predicate function. I'm still learning about REST and the WebAPI platform so if anyone can provide a better implementation, I certainly welcome it!

Comment: i'm making calls from mvc controller to web api controller. like a DMZ proxy. the code above makes sense, but that doesn't solve my problem. i could clean up my code a litte more using linq2json in the newtonsoft library, but for my code above works.

Comment: Swing and a miss! Did you come to a solution you were happy with? It seems like this might be one of those cases where you create an extension method to hide the confusion of the plumbing until something similar gets added to the framework. 

At any rate, I hadn't seen the CreateErrorResponse method before so thanks for that :)

Comment: yeah, it's all wrapped up in an extension method.